Would it be illegal for Companies House to require a response to a letter on registration?
It is a thing that people set up fraudulent companies using strangers addresses without authorisation.  Companies House appear to say they are legally blocked from preventing this:

Thousands of households have had their addresses unknowingly used by crime gangs to register bogus companies, a BBC investigation has revealed.
BBC Radio 4's You and Yours found about 150,000 had been registered and in some streets, every home had been targeted.
A Companies House spokesman said there were currently "no legal powers to verify or validate" a firm's details.
[Companies House is] a register which was set up in 1844 to be a register of companies and it has absolutely zero mandate to do any checking on any of the information.

This does not seem like a new or unusual problem, and most organisations are not prevented from doing the sort of minimal validation that could prevent this, even if not required to.  This has for a long time been implemented by sending mail to the provided address that requires a response.  It seems this could have been implemented at any time since 1844 with no obvious technical or legal hurdles.
Is there any law that restricts Companies House requiring some sort of verification of address such as requiring a response to a letter on registration?

The fact that Companies House is being used as a passive and unknowing participant in fraud doesn't necessarily mean that Companies House is the institution best suited to solving that problem at this point. Anti-fraud and anti-organized crime officials in law enforcement and Crown prosecutors certainly have the power to investigate and to prosecute those who misuse companies. Parliament could also reform the Companies Act to provide for minimal additional due diligence as part of the registration process.

@ohwilleke It is true that it does not NECESSARILY mean that Companies House should check that the primary point of contact given is actually controlled by the relevant entity, but considering how easy it would to be, how EVERY other thing you register for will ask you to prove the contact details given (when have you registered for something an not been sent a code to the email.phone), the importance of checking, and the time this has been a thing, it is a bit surprising they have not at least tried, or been forced to try.

There is a difference between "is legally blocked from doing X" (as you claim) and "has no legal powers to do X" (which is what the article says).

@Vicky, or also "instructed, funded, and staffed to do so"

Who doesn't recognise that while they do much good, neither the operations of Companies House, nor much else 'regulated' by the various Companies Acts, has anything like the effect most people believe?
I suggest that to everyone but the powers that be, it will remain clear until long after the cows come home that it matters very little whether Companies House now has powers to meet User65535's very obviously vital suggestions.
Companies House clearly should be be made to check what 65535 suggests, whether that means changing the law or simply enforcing compliance.

See Section 14 of the Companies Act 2006:

If the registrar is satisfied that the requirements of this Act as to
registration are complied with, he shall register the documents
delivered to him.

The requirements are set out here. They are based on various documents being "delivered to" companies house, and various statements that those documents must contain. By way of Section 14 above, if documents containing those statements are delivered to Companies House, then it must unconditionally register the company.
We could form a counter-argument. One of the statements that must be on the application, under Section 9(5) is:

a statement of the intended address of the company's registered
office, which must be an appropriate address within the meaning given
by section 86(2)

The part in italics was only recently added to the Act, so it's possible that Companies House might take a different position going forward. The article you linked to is from before the change.
Section 86(2) defines an "appropriate address" as follows:

An address is an “appropriate address” if, in the ordinary course of
events —  (a) a document addressed to the company, and delivered there
by hand or by post, would be expected to come to the attention of a
person acting on behalf of the company [...]

Taking all of the above, if the application uses someone else's address then it won't be an appropriate address, the requirements for registration will not have been met, and Companies House could refuse registration. It's not clear to me however that this gives Companies House the right to verify the accuracy of the address.
Regardless of whether they have the right to investigate, they certainly don't have the obligation. That's because of Section 13:

(1)The statement of compliance required to be delivered to the
registrar is a statement that the requirements of this Act as to
registration have been complied with.
(2)The registrar may accept the statement of compliance as sufficient
evidence of compliance.

The UK has a reputation for being a "business friendly" jurisdiction where there is relatively little red tape or expense involved in setting up a company. A big part of that is that the process of registration is straightforward, both for the new company and Companies House; it's essentially automated in most cases. This in turn enables Companies House to keep their fees extremely low. Prior to 1 May 2024, it only cost £12 to register a company. Even now it only costs £50. Those kinds of costs might be very difficult to maintain if Companies House had to take manual steps to verify information on each application it receives. I suspect this is the (non-legal) reason why they haven't implemented such a policy so far.

So the company is violating Section 9.5 if it uses an inappropriate address, but it's not Companies House's responsibility to enforce this. They're not a law enforcement organization, just a registrar.

Any letter sent to the address on companieshouse is legally delivered. So all they’d have to do is send a letter to that address and ask for verification. If they used my address, either I throw the letter away and thx company is not registered, or I reply telling them it’s not me, and the company is not registered. So that would be very little effort.

@gnasher729 except you’d be committing a crime by opening mail that is not addressed to you.

So the options are "throw the letter away" or write "not at this address" on the envelope and return it to sender

What does "if the registrar is satisfied" mean in legislative operational terms and in strictly legal terms?

@DaleM Only if the opener intends to act to a person’s detriment and without reasonable excuse.  See section 84(3) of the Postal Services Act 2000.  I always open letters arriving at my address to unfamiliar names in order to find out who is using my address wrongly (my reasonable excuse): over several years, a few of these have been related to fraud, and I have passed this information to the relevant bodies (banks, mobile phone companies etc.). Debt collection agencies using dubious practices wrongly make the same comment you did.

@gnasher729 You still have to print the letter, use an envelope, pay the postage, and pay staff to carry out those steps. There are around 800,000 companies registered each year. It will add up. I'm not arguing that it's a bad idea, just that Companies House fees are extremely low (e.g. compared to other government agencies) and they've achieved that by being very efficient and streamlined.

@civitas: To my understanding, "is satisfied that" is a Britishism for "believes that" (or maybe "reasonably believes that" or something along those lines).
